# Another way to vertically put some text over another text with equal size and centered spacing?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I can do that with `$ {a \atop b} $`
But can I write that in form of `$ \somecommand{a}{b} $` ? I would find it more readable while editing.

I use katex with joplin note taking app to write my math notes.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  What do you mean with ‘centred spacing’?

Comment: Is something like `\newcommand{\preatop}[2]{#1 \atop #2}` what you are looking for? The you can use `$\preatop{123}{456}$` for example.

Comment: centered spacing - when smaller text is in center of larger text in vertical space

Comment: If using @Marijn 's solution, it's probably best to write the definition as: `\newcommand{\preatop}[2]{{#1 \atop #2}}` (note extra braces) so that it will function in the context of a larger expression without having to employ the braces manually.

Comment: What are  the smaller text and the larger text?

Comment: @campa yes I have tried it, and it works as expected.

Comment: @Marijn What I meant is explained in the comment by Don Hosek. It works as long as it is the only formula. But try to put something before or after it and you'll get nasty surprises...

Comment: @campa for the original `\atop` you also need extra braces in that case - although I do admit that it is less obvious that you need to add braces in a `\cmd{a}{b}` syntax, so it would be preferred to add them in the definition as Don suggested.

Comment: @Bernard smaller text - text with lesser characters, larger text - text with more characters

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to mention that `stackengine` has some handy tools to realise what you want, if I've well understood: `\Centerstack` in text mode, `\Vectorstack` and some derived commands in math mode. The separator between lines is by default a blankspace.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

text
$ \Vectorstack{{a - c} {b + c}}\braceVectorstack{x y}=\bracketVectorstack{u v} $
text

\end{document}
```

[image]